# Transform external config in a web role

Tags: azure, slowcheetah

Can slowcheetah transform an external config file in an azure web role? e.g. I have logging info in log4net.config. But the transformed version does not get created when packaged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not manage to get slowCheetah working in my Azure solution. 
One alternative you can use is to create complete config files for each environment - e.g. :

- **log4net.debug.config**
- **log4net.release.config**

and copy the contents of these into the **log4net.config** at buildtime depending on the build configuration chosen.

This is done by adding a build target to your csproj file like so:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)log4net.config" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)log4net.$(Configuration).config" 
                     DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)log4net.config" />
</Target>
```

(*you may have to modify the paths in the script depending on where in the solution your config files are*)

You can find more information on MSBuild and manipulating your .csproj file [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx) and [here](http://pjbelfield.wordpress.com/2007/09/25/pre-build-events-and-the-before-build-target/)

Comment: This works well, and is a lot better than the batch file I was running to copy in the correct config.